# Issues with freezing Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pyinstaller

I just upgraded from Python 2.7 to 3.6.
I have a rather large script with a GUI which I had frozen to an .exe file with pyinstaller.

I have now made a few changes to the .py script and it works with the new Python version before I freeze it.

However, when I freeze I get a "Failed to execute script" message.
I tried to look into the error code and I traced the issue to the Pandas module.  Here is the error message:

```
C:\Users\MRCH\dist>My_File.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\pandas\_libs\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 714, in load_module
    module = loader.load_module(fullname)
  File "pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.tslib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "My_File.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
ImportError: C extension: No module named 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas' not built. 
**If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.**
[2032] Failed to execute script My_File
```

The error message suggest to import pandas by running 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' first. Where would I run this? It can't find the setup.py file if I run it from cmd?

Comment: Have you tried adding this module to the hiddenimports list? This can be added in the .spec file `hiddenimports = ['pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas']` or at the command line as an argument. If you edit the .spec file, make sure that you run pyinstaller as: `pyinstaller myfile.spec` This may be an easier option to try first, rather than the method suggested in the error message.

Comment: @apogalacticon is correct. You need to create a `hook-pandas.py` file for pyinstaller that looks like `hiddenimports = ['pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas']` Just add the hook to the pyinstaller hook folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@apogalacticon Thanks!

Adding the following line to the .spec file solved the problem:

```
hiddenimports = ['pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas']
```