# Import error when using pyinstaller to create a single exe file

Tags: python, executable, pyinstaller

I have a python package that involves several python modules. The project has been created in pycharm. I have used pyinstaller to create a single executable file of my python package. When I run the executable using a batch file I get an import error, specifically pandas has failed to be imported. Is there a reason why pyinstaller has not also collected the package dependencies in my virtual environment?

Thanks in advance for any help!

I have the following 2 errors: 
(1) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime'

(2) File "site-packages\pandas__init__.py", line 35, in 
ImportError: C extension: No module named 'pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime' not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.

Comment: are you asking for the reason pyinstaller did not collected the package dependencies from virtual env or how to correct the problem? I'm not clear about that

Comment: Both. I'd like to correct the problem but would also be interested to know why it didn't collect the package dependencies.

Comment: One quick question, did you use command prompt to build the exe using pyinstaller?

Comment: I used the anaconda prompt.

Answer (score 1):

There is one pip script for each virtual environment. So when you install a python module it get installed into the **projectname\venv\Lib\site-packages** directory.

When you run pyinstaller from terminal to make the executable, pyinstaller checks for dependencies in **Sys.path** . But that path does not include the **projectname\venv\Lib\site-packages** directory. Therefore pyinstaller cannot find those particular dependencies. In such cases it gives you warnings.Those warning can be found in **'warnname.txt'** near your executable file.

EDIT: **How to Configure pycharm to run pyinstaller**

1. First you need to add pyinstaller into project interpreter.
    [image]
2. Then you need to setup running configurations.
    [image]

   [image]

   **Script name:** path to your python script
    **working path:** Project location

   **leave interpreter options as it is in the image.**
3. Run pyinstaller. You can find your **.exe** in **dist directory**.
4. If the "Module not found" error still persists. You can add a hidden import hook and specify the names of the missing modules.Navigate to

> **Project Path\venv\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks**

and create a new **"hook-pandas.py"**(hook-modulename.py) script and make a list of hidden import modules like this.

```
hiddenimports = ['pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime','pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype','pandas._libs.skiplist']
```

5. And run pyinstaller again, and it should work now.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Think i'm doing something slightly wrong because i'm getting similar errors. I did this: pyi-makespec --paths=/path/to/thisdir \ --paths=/=/path/to/otherdir/myscript.py
wrote /path/to/workdir/.spec
now run pyinstaller.py to build the executable

(base) C:\Users\franc\PycharmProjects\test>pyinstaller.py
'pyinstaller.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I then did: pyinstaller --onefile myscript.py

Comment: When I did pyinstaller --onefile myscript.py after your instructions I still got warning messages. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: /path/to/thisdir means the path to the dependencies you want to collect, and after that you have to run pyinstaller scriptname.py

Comment: So when I run pyi-makespec I can check the spec file in folder and see that new path to dependencies has been added but then when I run pyinstaller scriptname.py the spec file is overwritten and so the dependency path is lost.

Comment: I figured this out - you need to run pyinstaller scriptname.spec. It's still not working though.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please refer it. It is tested.

Comment: Does main.py refer to the script I want to make executable or the script that runs pyisntaller?

Comment: script you want to make executable

Comment: This is still not working. I still get the same missing modules.

Comment: what is the module you used?  I tested this to make a .exe  from a .py which is using wx_python

Comment: and also interpreter option should be "-m PyInstaller". Capitalization is important.

Comment: missing module named numpy.core.maximum - imported by numpy.core, numpy.linalg.linalg
missing module named numpy.core.add - imported by numpy.core, numpy.linalg.linalg
missing module named numpy.core.complexfloating - imported by numpy.core, numpy.linalg.linalg
missing module named numpy.core.inexact - imported by numpy.core, numpy.linalg.linalg

Comment: I can actually make the executable but I get about 90 of the above missing module error

Comment: I also get multiple 
99457 WARNING: lib not found error messages during the process of making the exe file (the missing modules are in warnname.txt)

Comment: could you share the code? because I tested a simple code using numpy. It also had some missing module warnings. But it .exe gave me the expected results.

Comment: Okay that makes sense because when I am running the exe the only error I get is to do with the pandas package but I presumed that was just the first error it got and that there were also issues with the other packages. I now think this might be my problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49893124/issues-with-freezing-python-pandas?rq=1). In this answer they suggested I add the packages to the hidden imports in the spec file. Do you think that would work?

Comment: I was trying that just now, with pandas and numpy. It worked. Be sure to add all names you get as "module not found" errors. (**hiddenimports = ['pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime','pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype','pandas._libs.skiplist']**) . Like these two with me. Plus when you do this, be sure to delete spec file,dist and build before running pyinstaller again.